# How do I write a sed script to grep information from a text file

Tags: linux, sed, append, newline

I'm trying to do my homework that is restricted to only using `sed` to filter an input file to a certain format of output. Here is the input file (named `stocks`):

```
Symbol;Name;Volume
================================================

BAC;Bank of America Corporation Com;238,059,612
CSCO;Cisco Systems, Inc.;28,159,455
INTC;Intel Corporation;22,501,784
MSFT;Microsoft Corporation;23,363,118
VZ;Verizon Communications Inc. Com;5,744,385
KO;Coca-Cola Company (The) Common;3,752,569
MMM;3M Company Common Stock;1,660,453

================================================
```

And the output needs to be:

```
BAC, CSCO, INTC, MSFT, VZ, KO, MMM
```

I did come up with a solution, but it's not efficient. Here is my `sed` script (named `try.sed`):

```
/.*;.*;[0-9].*/ { N
N
N
N
N
N
s/\(.*\);.*;.*\n\(.*\);.*;.*\n\(.*\);.*;.*\n\(.*\);.*;.*\n\(.*\);.*;.*\n\(.*\);.*;.*\n\(.*\);.*;.*/\1, \2, \3, \4, \5, \6, \7/gp
}
```

The command that I run on shell is:

```
$ sed -nf try.sed stocks
```

My question is, is there a better way of using sed to get the same result? The script I wrote only works with 7 lines of data. If the data is longer, I need to re-modify my script. I'm not sure how I can make it any better, so I'm here asking for help!

Thanks for any recommendations.

Comment: +1 for admitting this is homework AND for that wild `s/\(.*\);....../` thingy you put in there! Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more way using `sed`:

```
sed -ne '/^====/,/^====/ { /;/ { s/;.*$// ; H } }; $ { g ; s/\n// ; s/\n/, /g ; p }' stocks
```

Output:

```
BAC, CSCO, INTC, MSFT, VZ, KO, MMM
```

Explanation:

```
-ne               # Process each input line without printing and execute next commands...
/^====/,/^====/   # For all lines between these...
{
  /;/             # If line has a semicolon...
  { 
    s/;.*$//      # Remove characters from first semicolon until end of line.
    H             # Append content to 'hold space'.
  }
};
$                 # In last input line...
{
  g               # Copy content of 'hold space' to 'pattern space' to work with it.
  s/\n//          # Remove first newline character.
  s/\n/, /g       # substitute the rest with output separator, comma in this case.
  p               # Print to output.
```

Comment: wow, thank you Birei!
I didn't know I can do double {} and I forgot I can just use substitute w/o g command to match 1st occurring match.  

I still have a few questions here. 
1. Why the last block is on the last line pattern ($)? 
2. For the 2nd substitution of new line. Is its purpose to remove empty line?    
2. For the last substitution of new line, how come it didn't replace the newline after the "MMM" ? 

You've gave me a great explanation but I still don't understand the purpose of $ {}. Hope you can help me understand it more. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @Jaycee: [1] I save desired strings in 'hold space' during the process of the file and only in last line recover that content, modify it and print. [2] `H` command appends `\n` plus the content of 'pattern space' to 'hold space', so at last line the content will be like `\nBAC\nCSCO\nINTC\nMSFT\nVZ\nKO\nMMM`. Then I remove first `\n` and substitute the rest of them with `, `

Comment: Ahhh..... I got it now!!!! Thank you so much!!!!! It's cool to use H and g.... =) Not sure why my teacher didn't teach us these commands. Thank you again!!!!! ^O^

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I've edited my algorithm, since I had neglected to consider the header and footer (I thought they were just for our benefit).

`sed`, by its design, accesses every line of an input file, and then performs expressions on ones that match some specification (or none). If you're tailoring your script to a certain number of lines, you're definitely doing something wrong! I won't write you a script since this is homework, but the general idea for one way to go about it is to write a script that does the following. Think of the ordering as the order things should be in a script.

1. Skip the first three lines using `d`, which deletes the pattern space and immediately moves on to the next line.
2. For each line that isn't a blank line, do the following steps. (This would all be in a single set of curly braces.)

   1. Replace everything after and including the first semicolon (`;`) with a comma-and-space (", ") using the `s` (substitute) command.
   2. Append the current pattern space into the [hold buffer](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-52) (look at `H`).
   3. Delete the pattern space and move on to the next line, like in step 1.
3. For each line that gets to this point in the script (should be the first blank line), retrieve the contents of the hold space into the pattern space. (This would be after the curly braces above.)
4. Substitute **all** newlines in the pattern space with nothing.
5. Next, substitute the last comma-and-space in the pattern space with nothing.
6. Finally, quit the program so you don't process any more lines. My script worked without this, but I'm not 100% sure why.

That being said, that's just one way to go about it. `sed` often offers varying ways of varying complexity to accomplish a task. A solution I wrote with this method is 10 lines long.

As a note, I don't bother suppressing printing (with `-n`) or manually printing (with `p`); each line is printed by default. My script runs like this:

```
$ sed -f companies.sed companies 
BAC, CSCO, INTC, MSFT, VZ, KO, MMM
```

Comment: @Jaycee Which part of the above are you having trouble with? I'd like to improve my explanation if I can!

Comment: hi, Dan, thanks for the hint. For 1st step, I'd get all symbols with a comma and a space. But I'm having trouble to do the 2nd step. How do I get each line that isn't the last line? Technically, MMM is not the last line. ============ is the last line. I'm so confused and really don't know how to proceed. Could you please elaborate a little more??? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I can get the last one as following:

/[0-9]$/ { N
N
s/\(.*\);.*;.*\n\n\=*/\1/gp
}

Comment: And the 1st step as following:

/[0-9]$/ {
s/\(.*\);.*;.*/\1, /g
}

Comment: Problem is... I still can't make all pieces together. =(

Comment: @Jaycee for my test program, I had gotten rid of the header and footer, which I thought were just illustrative and not part of the actual input. They've made the script a little more nasty. I've updated the above, but it's not pretty!

Comment: @Jaycee The substitution is okay (not as simple as it could be), but what you're doing is "append pattern space to hold buffer; replace hold buffer with pattern space; replace pattern space with hold space; replace newlines in pattern space". The first `H` is on the right track, but after that you want to abort (with `d`), and only use `g` later on, after the block you posted outside of its braces). Hope this pushes in the right direction! I know `sed` can be very difficult!

Comment: Hi, Dan,.... I think I'm almost there, but still missing some pieces. Here is my script:

1,/^$/d
/;/ {
s/\(.*\);.*;.*/\1, /
H
d
}
g
s/\n//g
p

The output prints twice of the line and there is a comma after MMM that should not be there. I've tried Birei's code and it does work. But I don't really understand why use ${} block and the order of the newline substitution. So, hope you can help me solve the last pieces!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Hi, Dan, thank you so much for all the help and suggestion!!! I now finally know how to use H and g. I didn't know there is a \n after getting the copy from hold space. And this \n character cannot be replaced as removing an empty line. (I thought it worked like an empty line.) 
Here is my code (with Birei's help):
`1,/^$/d
/;/ {
s/\(.*\)\(;.*;.*\)/\1/
H
d
}
$ {
g
s/\n//
s/\n/, /g
p
}`

But for 'd' command, do we need it to be there? I removed it from my script and is seems to work as well. Thank you soooo much on your time and so many knowledge!! I deeply appreciate!!!!!! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This sed command should produce your required output:

```
sed -rn '/[0-9]+$/{s/^([^;]*).*$/\1/p;}' file.txt
```

OR on Mac:

```
sed -En '/[0-9]+$/{s/^([^;]*).*$/\1/p;}' file.txt
```

Comment: Dear anubhava, I've run your command but the output is not in one line. One of the challenge is to replace all newline to comma and 1 space except the last line. There should not be a comma after the last one.

Comment: Yes my script behaves exactly like grep -o, since now I realize its a homework I will leave rest of the script to you.

Comment: @Jaycee Another hint for your answer is in the use of labels (as @Dan) suggested in his answer and use of `N` and **substituting** `newlines` with `,` and `space`

Comment: thanks Jaypal and Anubhava... I'm trying to read up more on labels on b and t commands. Although, I don't quite understand what t is doing yet......

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '1d;/;/{s/;.*//;H};${g;s/.//;s/\n/, /g;q};d' stocks
```

- We don't want the headings so let's delete them. `1d`
- All data items are delimited by `;`'s so let's concentrate on those lines. `/;/`
- Of the things above delete everything from the first `;` to the end of line and then stuff it away in the the hold space (HS) `{s/;.*//;H}`
- When you get to the last line, overwrite it with the HS using the `g` command, delete the first newline (generated by the `H` command), replace all subsequent newlines with a comma and a space  and print out what's left. `${g;s/.//;s/\n/, /g;q}`
- Delete everything else `d`

Here's a terminal session showing the incremental refinement of building a sed command:

```
cat <<! >stock # paste the file into a here doc and pass it on to a file
> Symbol;Name;Volume
> ================================================
> 
> BAC;Bank of America Corporation Com;238,059,612
> CSCO;Cisco Systems, Inc.;28,159,455
> INTC;Intel Corporation;22,501,784
> MSFT;Microsoft Corporation;23,363,118
> VZ;Verizon Communications Inc. Com;5,744,385
> KO;Coca-Cola Company (The) Common;3,752,569
> MMM;3M Company Common Stock;1,660,453
> 
> ================================================
> !
sed '1d;/;/!d' stock # delete headings and everything but data lines
BAC;Bank of America Corporation Com;238,059,612
CSCO;Cisco Systems, Inc.;28,159,455
INTC;Intel Corporation;22,501,784
MSFT;Microsoft Corporation;23,363,118
VZ;Verizon Communications Inc. Com;5,744,385
KO;Coca-Cola Company (The) Common;3,752,569
MMM;3M Company Common Stock;1,660,453
sed '1d;/;/{s/;.*//p};d' stock # delete all non essential data
BAC
CSCO
INTC
MSFT
VZ
KO
MMM
sed '1d;/;/{s/;.*//;H};${g;l};d' stock # use the l command to see what's really there!
\nBAC\nCSCO\nINTC\nMSFT\nVZ\nKO\nMMM$
sed '1d;/;/{s/;.*//;H};${g;s/.//;s/\n/, /g;l};d' stock # refine refine
BAC, CSCO, INTC, MSFT, VZ, KO, MMM$
sed '1d;/;/{s/;.*//;H};${g;s/.//;s/\n/, /g;q};d' stock # all done!
BAC, CSCO, INTC, MSFT, VZ, KO, MMM
```